# Select count of distinct occurrences of services per Client ID into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a new column that has the count of distinct service codes per Client ID. My last column in the second query has all 0s.

```
SELECT SERVICE_CODE, COUNT(SERVICE_CODE) AS SERVICE_COUNTS
FROM #TAPMAR
GROUP BY SERVICE_CODE

SELECT T.*, COALESCE(D.SERVICE_COUNTS, 0)
FROM #TAPMAR T
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT SERVICE_CODE, COUNT(*) AS SERVICE_COUNTS
   FROM #TAPMAR
   GROUP BY SERVICE_CODE) D ON D.SERVICE_CODE = T.CASE_NUM;
```

Comment: it means there is no row where `D.SERVICE_CODE = T.CASE_NUM` your `join` condition matches.

Comment: Sample data along with expected result set would help clarify your actual requirement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the `join` . . . I don't see why `service_code` should match `case_num`.

I would suggest window functions in any case:

```
SELECT T.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SERVICE_CODE) as NumOnService,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_NUM) as NumOnCase
FROM #TAPMAR T;
```

This adds the count fro both service and case.  I'm not sure which one you really want.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. Do you know how would I get the same counts for all values (not distinct count service codes) per Case_Num?

Comment: @Chris . . . I don't understand the concept.  Can you ask another question?